# Error 14 error C2041: illegal digit '8' for base '8'

Tags: c++, integer, switch-statement, constants, literals

while compiling this the switch statement got error in case 8 and 9

```
        srand(time(0));
        int random = (rand() %10) + 1;
        LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "random number for BVS [%d]",random);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 1:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Right Hand Thumb");
                random = 01;
                break;
            
            case 2:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Right Hand Index Finger");
                random = 02;
                break;

            case 3:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Right Hand Middle Finger");
                random = 03;
                break;
            
            case 4:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Right Ring Finger");
                random = 04;
                break;
            
            case 5:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Right Hand Baby Finger");
                random = 05;
                break;
            
            case 6:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Left Hand Thumb");
                random = 06;
                break;
            
            case 7:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Left Hand Index Finger");
                random = 07;
                break;

            case 8:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Left Hand Middle Finger");
                random = 08;
                break;
            
            case 9:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Left Ring Finger");
                random = 09;
                break;
            
            case 10:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Left Hand Baby Finger");
                random = 10;
                break;

            default:
                LogDebug.Log (atmID, 2, iThreadNo, "sendTransacMsgToRDV", "Random Number not generated successfully");
                break;

        }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9msBU.png)

facing this error while compiling the code

Comment: `08` is illegal because the prefix `0` means an octal base. just like the prefix `0x` is a hexadecimal base. octal legit digits are only 0-7. if you mean `8` don't write `08`. BTW `09` is also illegal

Comment: why did you write `random = 01;` and the other lines? `case 1:` means `random` is already equal to `1`, why assign `01` ?

Comment: For a [mcve], the **minimal** could express the issue with `int main() { int i = 08; }`

Comment: Looks like the `switch` statement is only discerning the 5th parameter.  IMHO, you should use the `switch` statement to set a string value.  After the `switch` statement, make the function call, using the string value as the 5th parameter.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why are you assigning values to `random` inside the case statements?  For example, when entering `case 1:`, you can guarantee that `random == 1`. You can remove all the `random` assignments in the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Integer literals starting from the digit `0` are octal integer literals in base 8.

From the C++ grammar

```
octal-literal:
    0
    octal-literal ’opt octal-digit
```

and

```
octal-digit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

So these records

```
random = 08;
```

and

```
random = 09;
```

is invalid. As you see for the base `8` valid digits are `0 -7` inclusive.

Just write

```
random = 8;
```

and

```
random = 9;
```

using decimal integer literals `8` and `9`.

And to avoid confusing readers of the code remove everywhere leading zeroes in integer literals.

Also it would be a good idea to introduce a scoped or unscoped enumeration for the constants and use them in case labels and in assignment statements.